# PHP > Returning allowed paths

Tags: php, arrays

*I already asked this question but it was published a little confusing and therefore proberbly not answered. So I try again with an extra example, if it's fine.*

There are original array's with url's like the one in example 1 and 2.
Every **last** folder of each element of the original array is the folder where some user has the right to view.

**Example 1**

```
Array(
'a'
'a/b/c'
'a/b/c/d/e'
'a/y'
'b/z'
'b/z/q
)
```

I would like to get a two array's like:

```
Array['short'](
'a/c/e'
'a/y'
'z/q'
)

Array['full'](
'a/b/c/d/e'
'a/y'
'b/z/q'
)
```

**Example 2**

```
Array(
'projects/projectA/books'
'projects/projectA/books/cooking/book1'
'projects/projectA/walls/wall'
'projects/projectX/walls/wall'
'projects/projectZ/'
'projects/projectZ/Wood/Cheese/Bacon'
)
```

I would like to get a two array's like:

```
Array['short'](
'books/book1'
'wall'
'wall'
'projectZ/Bacon'
)

Array['full'](
'projects/projectA/books/cooking/book1'
'projects/projectA/walls/wall'
'projects/projectX/walls/wall'
'projects/projectZ/Wood/Cheese/Bacon'
)
```

Comment: For future reference, the way to clarify a question that isn't clear is to edit the question, not re-ask it somewhere else.

Comment: And... I don't understand what you're trying to ask here.  What distinguishes the "full" paths from the "short" paths?

Comment: The short path's can be considered as sort of allowed visible breadcrums for the user.

The full paths will be used for encoded hyperlinks for those breadcrums.

Comment: ok but how should we derive them? there's no obvious way to know what the "short" form of the url should look like. what are the rules for producing them? there isn't a clear pattern. also if there's a relation betweem each pair of urls, maybe a better data structure would be an object or hash with two properties "short" and "long", so they can be paired together

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not fine, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45741262/edit) the first one and improve it - It will be bumped back to the homepage after that

Comment: They can be derived from the orininal array.

Comment: yes, but **how**? Like i said, there's no obvious pattern. what are the rules  you used in your examples to get from the input to the output? in example2 there aren't even the same number of entries in the output as there are in the input. so what defines the relationship between them all?

Comment: This isn't a question. It is just a list of arrays.

Comment: another example of uncertainty: where does "books/book1" come from? "books1" isn't there at all in the source array, and there's no other place in the results where a 1 gets appended to the result. So to write code whicj wotld implement that for the first element of the array, but not blindly repeat it, incorrectly, for all the others, we need to know how you decided  to do that? In what circumstances should we append 1 to a URL? this is just one of many ambiguous things in the examples.

Comment: @ADyson  In both examples the number of entrys are reduced by the result array.
The 'rule' as far as I can explain properly is that the number of single paths from the orininal array can be combined into less paths. So if a/b/c/d is an element. And a/b is an element. They could be combined to b/d. Because as I mentioned at the top of the description, only the ending folders are allowed to view.

Comment: @ADyson You said: Another example of uncertainty: where does "books/book1" come from? "books1" isn't there at all in the source array.

It's in the second element: ''projects/projectA/books/cooking/book1''.
Projects shoud be stripped as it isnt listed as an ending folder.
ProjectsA shoud be stripped as it isnt listed as an ending folder.
Cooking shoud be stripped as it isnt listed as an ending folder.

Comment: @medicalbird ok yeah I think I get it now, sorry. The original description you gave wasn't really sufficient. Since this is marked as duplicate I'll try and get an answer done for the original, if I can.

Answer (score 0):

@ADyson asks a very good question.  You've told us no rules governing what should be removed.  If I assume that you're simply looking to remove the first two elements of each array item, then you can...

```
$original_array = Array(
'projects/projectA/books',
'projects/projectA/books/cooking/book1',
'projects/projectA/walls/wall',
'projects/projectX/walls/wall',
'projects/projectZ/',
'projects/projectZ/Wood/Cheese/Bacon'
);

$new_array = array();
$new_array['full'] = array();
$new_array['short'] = array();

foreach($original_array as $full_url){
    $tmp = explode("/",$full_url);
    array_shift($tmp);
    array_shift($tmp);
    if(count($tmp)>1){
        array_push($new_array['full'], $full_url);
        array_push($new_array['short'], implode("/",$tmp));
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

However, I'm making a HUGE assumption about what you're trying to do and why you're trying to do it.  Therefore, I could be COMPLETELY WRONG.  This is why @ADyson is asking that you clarify the rules.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It isnt what I was looking for. I've commented at @ADyson.